# Convert a String with html code to Pdf format to fill in an itext element like a paragraph of a Document, with itext5, xmlworker

Tags: pdf, itext, xmlworkerhelper

I need to convert a String to fill an element of itext like a paragraph. I do not want to create a new document on the conversion, I just want it to receive a string and return something I could add as part of a pdf document.
An example of the input I need to convert is:

```
<h1>Hello<h1></br>
<h3>This is a test to demonstrate a simple html code I just need to convert</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your HTML string to elements and add these elements to a paragraph (by the way, I repaired your html string for the tests):

```java
String html = "<h1>Hello</h1><br/>\n" + 
        "<h3>This is a test to demonstrate a simple html code I just need to convert</h3>";
String css = null;
ElementList elements = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(html, css);
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
for (Element element : elements) {
    paragraph.add(element);
}
```

*(from [CreatePdf](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/xmlworker/CreatePdf.java#L79) test `testHtmlToParagraph`)*

After adding that `paragraph` to an iText `Document` you get:

[image: screen shot]

With a slightly more interesting `css`:

```java
String css = "h1 { background-color: lightblue; font-size: 20pt} h3 {font-family: verdana; text-align: center; color: red;}";
```

you get

[image: screen shot]

Comment: ¿what versions of itext and xmlworker did you use?, because i get an error with itext 5.5.13 and xmlworker 5.5.13 when i use your method....Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.pdfelement.NoNewLineParagraph.setMultipliedLeading(F)V
 at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.AbstractTagProcessor.currentContentToParagraph(AbstractTagProcessor.java:333)
 at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.Span.end(Span.java:76)
 at

Comment: I originally used the current 5.5.14-SNAPSHOT. After your comment, though, I switched to 5.5.13, but even with that version the code ran without issue. Concerning the method in question, by the way, the `setMultipliedLeading` method has not been changed since 5.4.5. Thus, I assume you additionally have a pre-5.4.5 version of itext or xmlworker in your classpath which is seen first by Java.

Comment: By the way, if you run across `NoSuchMethodError` outputs, you can count on your pre-compiled dependencies having non-matching versions.

Comment: Maybe I had a dependecies problem, but I still cant make it work. I get the error: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/itextpdf/tool/xml/ElementList;

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
             
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext-pdfa</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
             
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext-xtra</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
           
        </dependency>

Comment: By the way I have a jee project where Im using jsf 2.2 y primefaces 6.2

Comment: Do you have only those dependencies or others, too?

Comment: i also have: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.2</version>
           
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.13</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: Both Maven itself and most IDEs have features that allow to determine the effective dependencies you have and the cause for each of them, try those. Furthermore, you might have unexpected libraries in your JRE's lib folders or in some endorsed library folder. All I can say is that with matching, unmanipulated itext and xmlworker versions one does not get the `NoSuchMethodError`.